# text width in textedit or another program

Tags: textedit

How do you adjust text width?
I am sign writing a sign for a friend into timber,  all i want to do is print out the stencil so i can use it. Everytime   I enlarge the text the width changes ! I want tall skinny letters as I am limited on the sign length

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want your text to increase in height but not in width. The typical text editor/word processor doesn't support this, there are at least two options you could investigate on

- Get a proper word processor (Pages, LibreOffice, MS Word) and either pick or install a font which matches your need
- Get a drawing app which allows you to stretch images (a lot of them do) from the App Store

Comment: Thats exactly what i was asking  what drawing app would you recommend  and thank you

Comment: There are a lot of free ones in the App Store, so it's probably best to download a few and see which of them offers the functionality you need. From looking at the screenshots it seems that https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/eazydraw/id412624365?mt=12 might fit the bill.

Comment: I would make the text as large as possible in the drawing app, larger than the desired end result.  That way, any artifacts introduced while stretching tend to be resolved when you shrink it to sign size.